# Ошибка расширения интерфейса, при добавлении строчки export в код

Tags: typescript

Мне нужно расширить интерфейс элемента дом.
Реализовал таким образом. Тут всё без ошибок работает.

```
interface MyTileElement extends HTMLElement {
    tile: Tile;
}

interface Document {
    createElement(tagName: "space-tile"): MyTileElement;
}

class Tile {
    element: MyTileElement;

    constructor(){
        this.element = document.createElement("space-tile");
        this.element.tile = this;
    }
}

let n = 2;
```

Но стоит добавить экспорт или импорт, сразу typescript выдаёт исключение:

```
interface MyTileElement extends HTMLElement {
    tile: Tile;
}

interface Document {
    createElement(tagName: "space-tile"): MyTileElement;
}

class Tile {
    element: MyTileElement;

    constructor(){
        this.element = document.createElement("space-tile"); //Error:(13, 9) TS2322:Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'MyTileElement'.
                                                             // Property 'tile' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'.
        this.element.tile = this;
    }
}

let n = 2;
export {n}  // Добавленная строчка
```

Хотелось бы узнать почему такое происходит и как выйти из затруднения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему возникает данная ошибка, ответить не могу, но могу предложить вариант решения: нужно переместить интерфейсы в отдельный файл. Правда, придется выделить интерфейс у класса `Tile`, чтобы оборвать циклическую зависимость с типом `MyTileElement`.

Первый файл:

```
interface ITile {
    element: MyTileElement;
}

interface MyTileElement extends HTMLElement {
    tile: ITile;
}

interface Document {
    createElement(tagName: "space-tile"): MyTileElement;
}
```

Второй файл:

```
class Tile implements ITile {
    element: MyTileElement;

    constructor(){
        this.element = document.createElement("space-tile");
        this.element.tile = this;
    }
}

let n = 2;

export {n}
```

Comment: Не помогло. Импорт интерфейсов делаешь, и та же самая ошибка.

Comment: @МистерФикс а если первый файл сделать как `.d.ts`, тогда интерфейсы будут видны везде без импорта, или это не подходит?

Comment: может что-то ещё надо сделать? Файл переименовал, пробую по разному, но не видит интерфейсы, без импорта.

Comment: @МистерФикс не могли бы вы добавить в вопрос новый код, который не работает?

Comment: Решил через неймспейсы. Сделал одно пространство, и разбил его на файлы. Пока этого достаточно. У меня немного. В основном были интересны причины такого поведения, но я смотрю с русскоязычной информацией по тайпскрипту очень туго.

Comment: При втором заходе подключил модульность, или ещё что-то изменилось, но ваш способ работает. Спасибо :-)